# IONIC native plugin not working in IOINIC app

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a problem with IONIC, whenever I import a native plugin the application stops working.

Here I add the package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "noticias",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I am trying to use this plugin `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing`, but when importing it into the `app.component.ts` the application stops working.

This was the error displayed in the terminal:

[image: error]

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx'; ****

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    SocialSharing,****
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, 
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

As soon as I import the native plugin and update the application it stops working.

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code **or errors**. Anything text-based (code **and errors**) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

Hello is what you declared in your app.module.ts and add commands

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
and
npm install @ionic-native/social-sharing

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ...
  ],
  imports: [
  ...
  ],
  providers: [

// it must be declared here
   Social-sharing,

    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    ScreenOrientation,
    InAppBrowser,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, Here I added my app.component.ts, as soon as I import the native plugin and update the application it stops working.

Comment: Did you install with these commands in your project?                                               
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing  and 
npm install @ionic-native/social-sharing

Comment: Yes, I did all those steps but I don't understand why the application does not work.